# Chinese characters are not getting properly updated to DB via python script?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, character-encoding

**I am using python panda library to get data from CSV file and upload it SQL DB**

```
Last Name   First Name  Middle Name Full Legal Name
last擺田手1    first擺田手1   middle擺田手1  fulllegal1擺田手
Last擺田手2    first擺田手2   middle擺田手2  fulllegal擺田手
lastname6БдД    firstname6БдД   middlename6БдД  fulllegal6БдД
lastname7БдД    firstname7БдД   middlename7БдД  fulllegalname7БдД
lastname8БдД    firstname8БдД   middlename8БдД  fulllegalname8БдД
```

**Data is getting uploaded as below**

```
LastName    FirstName   MiddleName  FullLegalName
last???1    first???1   middle???1  fulllegal1???
Last???2    first???2   middle???2  fulllegal2???
lastname???3    firstname???3   middlename???3  fulllegal3???
lastname???4    firstname???4   middlename???4  fulllegalname4???
lastname???5    firstname???5   middlename???5  fulllegalname5???
```

**I have tried multiple encodings, but no solution.**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import datetime
 
def ImportDataToDB():
    servername = 'CWQ00xxxxx.xxxxxx.com'
    dbname = 'AbbottRPA'
    Input_file = 'C:/Users/AKARAPX/Desktop/Corptesting/SOX Workday Report (DRS) 2023-11-13 05_56 CST.csv'
    table1 = 'CAWD_TX_Main'
    CreatedBy = 'AKARAPX'
  
    try:
        conn = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@' + servername + '/' + dbname + '?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')

        #print('Connection successful')

        df_csvdata = pd.read_csv(Input_file, encoding="utf-8")

        columns_to_keep = ['Last Name','First Name','Middle Name',]
        df_csvdata = df_csvdata[columns_to_keep]
 
        df_csvdata.to_sql(table1, con = conn, schema = 'rpa', if_exists='append', index=False)
        print('Data inserted successfully')
   

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

ImportDataToDB()
```

Comment: What is your table schema in SQL Server.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78038841/edit) your question to include the DDL of the `[rpa].[CAWD_TX_Main]` table in SQL Server, including all column collations. Unless you're on SQL Server 2019 or 2022 and have to correct collations applied it's unlikely to support UTF-8 encoding.